# How to get the shape of an array created with np.random.randint(1,7,(10,3))

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, random, shapes

As you see, I created and array but I specify a tuple as the third argument. I thought that I would simply do this code to get the shape.

```
X.shape()
```

But I receive an error stating that **a tuple was not callable**. I am using numpy v1.23 with python 3.10.4 and inside the console of Spyder 5.

Any suggestion to get that result?

Thank you in advance for your help.
Mario

I Google it and I never find the answer I am looking for

Comment: I have just found that I don't have to put the ( ) at the end of shape. I did X.shape and I got what I wanted. I put my finding in case someone ask the same thing. If it's not pertinent, jyust delete my question.

Comment: The general rule in Python is that the `.method()` is used to call the method via __call__ and `.method` will see the object. So, if you want the object, use `.method`. If it returns a function, you can try `.method()` as it will call (run) the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`X.shape` is not a method but a class attribute and hence not callable, i.e. cannot be called like a function with parentheses. You can just access it like any other class attribute.

```py
import numpy as np

arr = np.random.randint(1, 7, (10, 3))

print(arr.shape)
```

Expected output:

```
(10, 3)
```